Advice for how many conferences humanities PhDs should be presenting at per year from experienced hiring committee members?
Do people who have been involved with hiring at colleges and universities know how many conferences papers PhD students (in the humanities) should be presenting per year in this job-market? I have started out with 2 per year (usually one at my institution and one external) but am unsure if this is a bare minimum or the ideal number.
If it matters, I am working in the theological/religion/philosophy fields.
Thank you!
